# What is Declarative Meta-Programming?

Tags: metaprogramming, declarative

I understand what is meta-programming and what is declarative programming.  Is their fusion DeclarativeMetaProgramming combines the aspect of both of them, and/or it adds few more things into it? Is there any programming language inexistence can do this, without, using code generators?